# Don't fire trigger if another trigger is active

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I'm using a ToggleButton control. I have triggers for the IsChecked and IsMouseOver properties that change the background and foreground colors. I don't want the IsMouseOver trigger to fire if the ToggleButton is checked. Is this possible?

My current triggers for the ToggleButton:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ControlSelectedBrush}"/>
        <Setter TargetName="ToggleButtonText" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ControlSelectedTextBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ToggleButtonText" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ControlHoverBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`MultiTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger.aspx) and define that as an additional condition.

i.e.

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter TargetName="ToggleButtonText" Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource ControlHoverBrush}" />
</MultiTrigger>
```